# How to compare source in Git repository between source in SVN repository

Tags: svn, git

how do I compare code in two different repository types?  The Git repository was not taken from the SVN repository.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use meld (open source) for folders/files compare

Comment: meld is cool, but when i compare folders, it shows empty folders, even if there is no differences

Answer (score 2):

Check them both out to disk and use a tool like [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).